# SQL Join Query for Solution for A(Table) selected and B(table) all Record

Tags: sql, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ELIU.png)

```
SELECT 
    TR.UserKeyCode, TR.ProductID, TR.Line_No 
FROM  
    TBLT_RESULTDTL_DONE TR 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    TBLM_PRODUCT TP ON TR.ProductID = TP.ProductID
WHERE  
    TR.UserKeyCode = 'E01_00001' AND TR.QustionID = 1
```

Result:

```
 E01_00001  11  1 
 E01_00001  36  2  
 E01_00001  16  3
```

Product table all results and  Result record 3 only i need others will be null

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: E01_00001 11 1

E01_00001 36 2

E01_00001 16 3

Comment: @sanujdananjaya expected outpur

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    TR.UserKeyCode, TR.ProductID, TR.Line_No 
FROM  
    TBLM_PRODUCT TP 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    TBLT_RESULTDTL_DONE TR ON TR.ProductID = TP.ProductID and  TR.UserKeyCode = 'E01_00001' AND TR.QustionID = 1
```

Comment: i need only line_no will be null

Comment: you need line_no only for TR.UserKeyCode = 'E01_00001'